# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateDocs does not exist

Tags: laravel, validation

This issue appears after I submit a form and run form validation, even though my form validation is functioning on another page in that file.

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateDocs does not exist.

```
  public function store(Request $request) {


    $request->validate([
      'title' => 'required',
      'category' => 'required',
      'content' => 'required|min:50',
      'file' => 'required|docs|mimes:txt,pdf,ppt|max:2048'


    $docsName = time() . '.'. $request->file->extension();
    // $request->docs->move(public_path('docs'), $docsName);
    $request->file->storeAs('public/docs', $docsName);

    $postData = ['title' => $request->title, 'category' => $request->category, 'content' => $request->content, 'docs' => $docsName];

    Post::create($postData);
      return redirect('/post')->with(['message' => 'Post added successfully!', 'status' => 'success']);
    }
```

Comment: There are no validation rule “docs” - and in cannot working in another form.

Comment: As Maksim said, you have "'file' => 'required|docs" and there's no rule "docs" among these rules: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules